# Can I use my iMac's mic and speakers for a call with my android 2.2 phone (through Bluetooth)?

Tags: bluetooth, calls, bluetooth-audio

I'd like to use my iMac's audio (i.e., microphone and speakers) for a call that is handled on my Samsung galaxy i5000 Android 2.2 phone. Is that possible?

I've paired my iMac (OSX 10.6) and smartphone through Bluetooth.
Then, during a call, I opened the context menu on my phone (where you can also enable/disable the speaker of the phone), but the Bluetooth icon is disabled. (although Bluetooth itself is active and working, e.g. from my iMac I can see the files on my phone).

Is there any way to get the above working?

*(I wondered whether to post this under apple- or android-stackexchange, but given the Bluetooth icon being disabled, I decided to post it here)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the Bluetooth icon being disabled is that you haven't paired the phone with a device that supports the [Headset profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Headset_Profile_.28HSP.29). Bluetooth uses profiles to categorize which services a device supports, and Macs don't support acting as a headset, only connecting to a headset (see [list of supported profiles](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10549)).

To use this functionality, you'd need additional software which enables the Mac to act as a headset and connect to a headset gateway (which your phone most likely supports).